# Passphrase lost for my wallet.dat

Tags: litecoin, wallet.dat, litecoin-qt, wallet-recovery

I need help to unlock my passphrase. I don't remember setting up one, but now there is a pasphrase. Eitherway I am unable to send out coins from my LitecoinQt to the exchange.

Comment: unfortunately there is no easy way to recover the password, you can try bruteforce but you will need a lot of computing power

Comment: Do you recall **any** possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't remember setting up a passphrase?
Either you did do it yourself, or someone else had access to your computer and set a passphrase, effectively disabling your money.

Answer (score 1):

Did you:

1. Change your client software?
2. Change your operating system?
3. Install Updates eg. Java/Qt/...?
4. Swap ISP?
5. Checked blockchain.info (for transactions on your wallet?)

My first assumption would be that you got hacked (if your wallet.dat was in it's predefined environment) and that the one controlling has added as password *or* you have encountered a bug somewhere which has not been reported and fixed.

If you could add your litcoin address(es) I can do some investigation.

Thank you.

Best regards,

Nico

Comment: It's unclear why a hacker would add a passphrase to someone else's wallet, when it would be more effective to just copy the private keys and transfer the coins to their own address.  Unless they did it by mistake.

Comment: I've had issues before with TeamViewer where the keyboard's symbols are either wrong (eg € or £ instead of &) or dead keys are hit making c` into ć

Comment: @NateEldredge not entirely true. I had a test system for malware for Windows wallets and EXEcoin had malware which encrypted the dat file and tried to send it via ftp. It's plausible malware malcontents would wait if the wallet showed significant activity ie to wait for more BTC from those keys. But it's much more likely OP forgot the password

Comment: @NateEldredge It would be marginally less suspicious to encrypt the wallet than delete it or steal them outright. Encrypting it is something you might do and forget about.